# How to print only selected checkbox list in HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have to print the PDF page only of the items that are selected with the checkbox.

```
    <td>Prima riga</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control autosize" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Seconda riga</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control autosize" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Terza riga</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control autosize" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introduce a class `.hidden-on-print` defined like this:

```css
@media print {
  .hidden-on-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Now all you have to do is add/remove this class to the closest `tr` when the checkbox is changed.

```js
// initialize
document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]").forEach((chk) => {
  chk.checked = false
  chk.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.closest("tr").classList.remove("hidden-on-print");
    } else {
      this.closest("tr").classList.add("hidden-on-print");
    }
  })
})
document.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(tr => tr.classList.add("hidden-on-print"))
```

```css
@media print {
  .hidden-on-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="id1">Prima riga</label></td>
    <td><input id="id1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control autosize" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="id2">Seconda riga</label></td>
    <td><input id="id2" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control autosize" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="id3">Terza riga</label></td>
    <td><input id="id3" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control autosize" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="print()">print</button>
```